# Jsoup: get text from all children elements

Tags: java, jsoup

In a document I try to parse there is this element:

```
<span class="location accessible-contrast-color-location">
    Seattle, WA 98104 
    <span style="font-size: smaller">(Downtown area)</span>
</span>
```

I try to get the text `Seattle, WA 98104 (Downtown area)` from it, however only get `Seattle, WA 98104`, using this code:

```
Element locationElement = companyWrapper.selectFirst(".location");
System.out.println((locationElement != null ? locationElement.text() : ""));
```

I thought `text()` should take the text inside both the parent element and its children, however it doesn't seem to be the case?

**EDIT**:

```
Elements jobElements  =
        doc.select(".jobsearch-SerpJobCard.unifiedRow");
Element companyWrapper = jobElement.selectFirst(".sjcl");
```

Comment: Which Jsoup version are you using? I'm using 1.11.3 and my output is "Seattle, WA 98104(Downtown area)"

Comment: `1.11.3` version as well, added with Maven. Hella weird!

Comment: How do you instantiate `companyWrapper`? Can you add the code?

Comment: @TDG Yeah, see edit. It's a parser for https://www.indeed.com/q-Java-Developer-l-Seattle-jobs.html

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

You can fetch elements text via CSS class names. for this purpose  you must use `doc.select("span.location").text();`

In this case, you have a element that has one child, and when you call `text` method, the text of the main node (Seattle, WA 98104) and its child (Downtown area) is fetched.

The code is as follows

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {


    String html = "<span class=\"location accessible-contrast-color-location\">" +
            "Seattle, WA 98104" +
            "<span style=\"font-size: smaller\">(Downtown area)</span>" +
            "</span>";


    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
    String result = doc.select("span.location").text();
    System.out.println(result);


}
```

---

**Solution 2**

You can also use the `tag` name to get the text of it and its child.

I coded your scenario with the help of span `tag`.

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {


        String html= "<span class=\"location accessible-contrast-color-location\">" +
                "Seattle, WA 98104" +
                "<span style=\"font-size: smaller\">(Downtown area)</span>" +
                "</span>";


        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
        String result= doc.select("span").first().text();
        System.out.println(result);
    }
```

Notice that, since you want both texts, you must get the first `span` tag, because it contains the child tag, so you can fetch parent tag text ((Seattle, WA 98104)) as well as the child tag text(Downtown area) from it.